# Zariski or algebraic criterion for generic point of a projective k-variety or are both equivalent? (near elementary alg.geom.)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, soft-question, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

**To begin with**, I am currently on what one could call elementary / classical algebraic geometry. OK in algebraic geometry almost everything is above elementary level ... but I don't imply simple. The level I mean is where one has a field $k$ and an algebraically closed field $K$ containing $k$ - and often the transcendence degree of $K$ over $k$ is infinite, then one says the first is an universal domain for the second. One then considers special subsets of affine space $K^n$ or projective space $(K^{n+1} \setminus \{0\})  / R$,  where $R(x,y)$ is the equivalence relation (between $x$ and $y$) "there exists a non-zero $t\in K$ such that $y=tx$", any of these special subsets being the solution set of a system of polynomial equations with coefficients in $k$ (in the affine case, the projective case is a bit more complicated, but similar).

So please no answer mentioning schemes and higher. Best also no absolute varieties (let it be simple by staying "in $k$") nor abstract varieties (my question concerns affine & projective spaces which can be dealt without those, even if e.g. S. Lang introduces projective alg. geom. only in that frame - see below author+title for my two books on alg. geom.)

**My question**:

*Introductory remarks.* I appreciate the use of what is often called the Zariski ($k$-) topology (where the closed subsets are those algebraic over $k$) and the concept of a generic point of a $k$-variety can be defined from a general definition of a generic point in a topological space, using the Zariski topology. This works well in the affine case, i.e. leads to an equivalent algebraic property that agrees with the usual definition in algebraic geometry. For the projective case, I am less sure. This definition method works in both cases for the concept of *irreducibility*, it makes some proofs easier to expose and understand.

So I am facing this *problem*: For the definition of a generic point of a projective variety $H$ one can use:

a) the definition via the Zariski topology of projective space (which happens to be identical with the quotient topology of the topology induced from the Zariski topology of affine space to its part with 0 removed, as I could easily verify): in a topological space $X$ a point $a$ is by definition generic when the singleton $\{a\}$ is dense in $X$

b) the usual algebraic definition of a generic point as one finds it e.g. in the book referenced below as (2) specifically for projective space (after all, it cannot be the same as for affine space!) In the next § I try to "translate" the relevant passage of this book that could be the definition; from French but also from its mathematical presentation, which isn't quite clear to me any way (it is difficult to take it out of its context, but my translation might be a valid definition and that is then what I mean in what follows)

Let $\Pi$ denote the above mentioned n-dimensional projective space, $x \in \Pi$, and let $\hat x$ be a system of  homogeneous coordinates of $x$ - which means coordinates of a point $P$ of the affine space above mentioned (with dim. $n+1$ instead of $n$) such that $x$ is the class of $P$ modulo $R$. We say that $x$ is a generic point of $H$ when we have:

A point $y \in \Pi$ belongs to $H$ if and only if it satisfies following statement:
For every element $f$ of the ring of polynomials in $n+1$ indeterminates over $k$ such that $f(\hat x)=0$ and every system $\hat y$ of homogeneous coordinates of $y$, one has $f(\hat y)=0$. [*I will later reference to this § under the name **(Spec)** for "specialisation" - it contains what Samuel names (Sp) but a bit more ...*]

*Comment to this definition*: it seems to depend on the choice of $\hat x$ ... which makes little sense. BTW this passage is followed in the book by a statement that $\hat x$ is a system of *strictly* homogenous coordinates - a rather weird terminology which adds the restriction that $k(\hat x)$ is transcendental over $k(x)$ ... the author has first constructed (in the former context) a point $x$ and then says that such a point is said to be a generic point of $H$ - so this restriction might be a part of the definition (but probably not) - ... and finally he introduces a similar property using only homogeneous polynomials for f, and in this case the independance from the choice of $\hat x$ seems garantied ... really the whole is lacking clarity. I suppose others books say essentially the same but much clearer ...

Now: **do a) and b) agree?** *If not, which definition is standard? If they do, could someone help me for the proof?* One thing I know is that in one direction the implication works, due to a simple result I found: if a map from $X$ to $Y$ (top. spaces) is continuous and surjective, then the image of a generic point is a generic point. May-be a similar result could settle the question in the other direction.

As a justification to a), the German Wikipedia says in the article on this idea [my translation]: *The concept of a **generic point** belongs to the mathematical subject of point-set topology, but it has its main application in algebraic geometry*.

The tag "soft question" does not concern the whole question, it is here because definitions and the current standards about them can change. The part about possible equivalence of two definitions is not included in its scope.

*References to books on algebraic geometry I am using:*

(1) Serge Lang: Introduction to Algebraic Geometry

(2) Pierre Samuel: Méthodes d'algèbre abstraite en géométrie algébrique

Comment: Maybe you might find something useful if you use the keyword "Weil foundations". It's rather out of fashion these days though...

Comment: The definition of a generic point in the sense of Weil's foundations is fairly obscure these days - few readers will know it off the top of their head, and few readers will be willing to go track down a copy of Samuel's book to acquaint themselves with it. Why not add the definition you're interested in to your post?

Comment: How do you even discuss "generic points" without scheme theory? That's where I saw them appear for the first time. 

You take a "classical" variety, take its associated set of irreducible subvarieties, and a point is considered generic if it is dense as a singleton subset in the set of irreducible varieties, endowed with the specific topology it receives from the variety. I know you said no scheme theory, but that's the only definition I know.

Comment: You seem to be very interested in algebraic geometry if you are in such a specific context. Why not learn scheme theory? It would take some time, but you seem to be willing to get your hands dirty anyway.

Happy to discuss further.

Comment: @KReiser I have edited my Q. to include a (trial) definition out of Samuel's book - some might recognize that as a (problematic) version of a similar definition seen elsewhere. Read again from the § beginning with b) until the line before "Now do a) and b) agree"

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, with a better motivation I might later penetrate into schemes, but for the moment I'd like to solve my problem with the litterature I am at.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, BTW your answer seems to imply that a) is now the definition that has consensus. But on the condition that the topology is the one I mentioned. (Don't try to tell me yours in the scheme theory, I might not understand it easily - instead confirm or refute that in the projective case it's the one I call Zariski's.)

Comment: @UlysseKeller: I don't understand what you're writing because your definitions are not precise (no offense); you didn't exactly provide the definition that you call "Zariski's", and your apparent fear of schemes tells me you might not understand it, although it's quite simple. So I'll risk offending you and give it to you anyway in the hope that it might enlighten you despite your warnings.

Comment: Yes, a generic point in the topological sense is defined as the element of a singleton which is dense, like you said, i.e. $a \in X$ is generic if $\{a\}$ is dense in $X$. But alone this is not enlightening since you don't have examples. In affine space $\mathbb A^n$ over an algebraically closed field $K$, the points you are used to are the ones with coordinates $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ with $a_i \in K$. But in algebraic geometry, we are interested in the set of all irreducible closed subsets in the Zariski topology. Those correspond to irreducible algebraic subvarieties.

Comment: Algebraic subvarieties in the case of affine space are just subsets defined as the zeroes of algebraic equations. They are irreducible when they cannot be written as the finite union of closed subsets (*finite* being the main constraint here). For instance, in $\mathbb A^2$, the equation $xy=0$ defines a closed subset, but it is the union of the closed subsets $x=0$ and $y=0$. So in the plane, irreducible closed subsets correspond to either (classical) points, irreducible polynomials (which are then 1-dimensional subvarieties, i.e. curves), and the whole plane.

Comment: Continuing that example, now consider the set of all irreducible closed subsets. In $\mathbb A^2$, that means the set that contains all (classical) points, curves (which are irreducible), and the whole plane. That set can be endowed with the "Zariski topology"; you can basically say that $\overline{ \{a \}}$ is equal to $\{a\}$ if $a$ is a point, $\{a\} \cup \{ \text{ points in } a \}$ if $a$ is a curve, and it's the whole thing if $a$ is the point corresponding to the plane ($a$, with the curves and the points).

Comment: So the closure of a point in the set of irreducible algebraic varieties is the set of all irreducible algebraic subvarieties contained in it. And then you define closed subsets of that thing as finite unions of closures of points. The weird part is that in that set, a point is an irreducible algebraic subvariety of your original space. But that's the *main example* of a generic point. If $X$ is an irreducible algebraic variety, then $\{X\}$ is a generic point for that new space I just constructed. In case you didn't know it's name, it's called the spectrum of the coordinate ring of $X$.

Comment: I don't know any other relevant topological spaces admitting interesting generic points; they are always (at least locally) spectra of rings. So if you are interested in generic points, you should try to understand that example.

Comment: In projective space for example, you get an example of the "at least locally" part. The $n$-dimensional projective space is covered by $n+1$ copies of $n$-dimensional affine space who form open subsets of it. But all these open subsets share the same generic point; open subsets of irreducible varieties are dense in algebraic geometry, and since the generic point is also dense, the generic point is always part of that open subset.

Comment: I don't think I am missing examples. But I do still miss better intuitions of the contents of alg. geometry ... Intuition is not part of math' itself, BUT it helps understanding proofs (and definitions) and I guess it is also essential for FINDING proofs

Comment: Concerning my imprecise definitions. For b) it comes from the book as I said. For a) I mentioned it, saying: in a topological space X a point a is by definition generic when the singleton {a} is dense in X This is precise and there seems to be no contradictors to it (in other words, it is consensus) BUT of course this doesn't define the concept of a generic point in geometry. To do this (for the moment only in 'canonic' affine / projective space) one has to explain what topology is used. It's the topology I consider as Zariski's, not the criterion using this topol'. (continued)

Comment: (cont. of my last cmt:) I have explained that for both affine and projective spaces, Zariski's topology is the one where the algebraic sets over k are the closed subsets. There is no doubt about this for me in the affine frame, but in the projective one, I am not absolutely sure, but I would be surprised if this is not the topology to use to apply the topol. def. of a generic point

Comment: So let's agree - until an improbable contradiction by someone else - to use a) as the definition of a generic point ALSO in the projective frame. Then the question remains: do a) and b) agree? There is in Samuel's book a similar definition to b) for the affine case. I have not verified completely but I am nearly sure that a) and b) agree with it in the affine frame.

Comment: Something I missed to introduce in my Q. is to say what I already have found by myself aiming at an answer - in principle a 'must' in this forum - I will now come with this because in fact, it will make it much easier for anyone incl. myself to come to a complete answer. But I will not enter this as an edit of my Q. nor as some more comments, but as a PARTIAL answer to my own Q. - after all partial answers - as formal answers! - are OK by the forum rules, but seldom given because people seem afraid of giving as answer what might be frustrating because it does not (yet) settle the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions are equivalent, of course.

For convenience, let me define some notation.
Let $\mathbb{P}^n$ be projective $n$-space.
For any subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$, let $I (X)$ be the set of all *homogeneous* polynomials $f$ in $n  + 1$ variables with coefficients in $k$ such that $f (x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$.
Dually, for any set $F$ of *homogeneous* polynomials in $n + 1$ variables with coefficients in $k$, let $V (F)$ be the set of all $x \in \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $f (x) = 0$ for all $f \in F$.

(The condition $f (x) = 0$ does not depend on the specific homogeneous coordinates chosen for $x$: homogenous coordinates for a point in projective space are related by scalar multiplication, and homogeneity of $f$ means scalar multiplication of the input becomes scalar multiplication of the output, but scalar multiplication acts trivially on $0$.
It is essential that we restrict attention to homogeneous polynomials, however.)

Recall that the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the one where the closed subsets are precisely those $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $X = V (F)$ for some $F$.
It is straightforward to verify the following:

**Lemma.**
For $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$, the closure of $X$ (with respect to the Zariski topology) is $V (I (X))$.

Thus, given a closed subset $H \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$, $x \in H$ is generic in the sense of topology if and only if $H = V (I (\{ x \}))$.
But $I (\{ x \})$ is by definition the set of homogeneous polynomials $f$ (etc.) such that $f (x) = 0$, so $V (I (\{ x \}))$ is the set of all $y \in \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $f (y) = 0$ for all homogeneous polynomials $f$  such that $f (x) = 0$.
Hence $H = V (I (\{ x \}))$ is the statement that $x \in H$ is generic in the sense of algebra.

Let me remark that not every closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$ has a generic point.
The ones that do are precisely the irreducible closed subsets.

(Let me also remark to scheme theorists: in this setup, generic points are not unique – indeed, there will be infinitely many of them!
To get any generic points at all we need $K$ to be a transcendental extension of $k$, and to get generic points for everything we need algebraic closedness and infinite transcendence degree.
This is *different* from the setup of e.g. Hartshorne Ch. I!
It is essentially inspired by the practice of studying algebraic varieties defined over algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ by looking at their $\mathbb{C}$-points – indeed, taking $k = \mathbb{Q}$ and $K = \mathbb{C}$ fits the requirements of this setup.)

Comment: Thank you, looks good. I need time to see it fits my context. It's much like what I have for the affine case: your lemma "copies" a result in that one - its proof may be similar. (Then the result I mention in my answer isn't needed.) Just a little remark about your notations: the use of I(X) suggests that this is an ideal - like the analogous object in the affine case - which it is *not*. But it generates a homogeneous ideal (which could be used instead): a set of homogeneous polynomials does that, but the ideal also contains non homogeneous elements, so isn't equal to I(X)

Comment: Indeed, but I prefer to avoid having to discuss non-homogeneous polynomials at all in this context.

Comment: I could use your answer to my satisfaction. The first step was to clear up the criterions from Samuel's book - not *(Spec)* but the second one following it (see the § *Comment to this definition* in my Q,) is what is really needed - and then obtain its equivalence with one resembling your H=V(I({x})). A reasoning similar to yours but with the full homogeneous ideal completed the argument. The lemma (with said ideal) can be proved exactly like the corresponding result in the affine case.

Comment: BTW: I added an edit to *my* answer (to which the reader is now directed at its beginning)

Answer (score 0):

*A **partial** answer* (can be ignored now, please read the **edit** at the end):

When I (= also the author of the Q.) studied (long ago, in the 1990's!) the affine case and in it the concept of generic points, I did not use Samuel's book, but Lang's (see references (1) and (2) in my orig. post). Interestingly (and surpringly for me now in memory) Lang also *does not* use Zariski's topology until he intoduces it much later in the book in the chapter on absolute varieties. But in my notes from that time I *did* introduce Zariski's topology for the affine frame (quasi from the beginning) e.g. also for the concept of *irreducibility* of alg. $k$-sets, using topology to simplify arguments. I wonder where I took that from ... not from Wikipedia, which did not yet exist then, may-be from a book I lent from library a short time. Any way, my old notes include a property of gen. points which I am nearly sure are easily seen to be equivalent to what Samuel gives similar to b) for the affine case. Using *that* property and other facts related to it (from my notes) *plus* results on the projective case I documented before the dealing with gen. points in proj. space, I found - and proved to my satisfaction - following result (my proof I have not kept - details too long - but the whole context makes me pretty sure that it is OK, so if a reader of this has a doubt, I suggest he just "verifies it intuitively") :

Let $\hat x$ be a non-zero point of affine space over $\Pi$. Then what is said in the § of my Q. *now named **(Spec)*** holds if and only if $\hat x$ is a generic point of $C(H)$. This symbol stands for the cone in the affine space over $H$, which is by def. $\{ 0 \} \cup \phi^{-1}(H)$ where $\phi$ denotes the canonical map from the affine space minus $0$ to $\Pi$. (This cone is irreducible iff $H$ is irreducible, provided $H$ isn't empty. This is a hypothesis here since I use the def. of variety that includes irreducibility.) In what follows I consider the result mentioned here for granted; it uses "generic point" only in the affine frame, which should not be at risk of misunderstanding, all definitions one might consider being equivalent with little doubt. I haven't given one explicitely but a def. is included in what follows now.

Now let's agree that a) is the definition of a generic point in both settings (aff. & proj.), in other words, one has the defintion in a topological space of Zariski style: a point $a$ of an irreducible subset $X$ is a generic point of $X$ *iff* the singleton $\{a \}$ is dense in $X$ - and the closed (resp. the irreducible) subsets for Zariski's topology are the sets algebraic over $k$ (resp. the $k-$varieties) defined as usual (I hope the def. of these concepts are unchallenged, also in the proj. frame.)

Now the question remains open: do a) and b) agree? At this point, I leave open to clear the aspects of b) that might need it, because a possible gap will have to be filled later. For the moment the key result which seems to be needed is this:

A non-zero point $\hat x$ of affine space is a generic point of $C(H)$ if and only if $x$ is a generic point of $H$.

May-be this is not true as it stands, in that case what simple change will make it true?

Any way, the canonical map I called $\phi$ is continuous, so that one sees easily by elementary topology that it maps a generic point of a (irreducible) subset $A$ to a generic point of $\phi(A)$. But $\phi$ is also the can. map from a space to a quotient space of it. Using that plus may-be some special property of the equivalence relation $R$ will I hope complete the reasoning ... for example, is $R$ an open equ. rel. (meaning the can. map is open) as lets me think something I read?

**Edit**: this "program" has not been realized. *Instead* the answer given by Zhen Lin together with what I describe in my comment to it beginning with "I could use your answer" settled my question. If a (casual) reader really needs an answer to my question, it is almost sure that s/he is studying Samuel's book and then these indications will hopefully help him/her too